# tie primary key from table to checkedlistbox items to prevent issues with table changes

Tags: vb.net

I have a checkedlistbox that is populated from the records in a table in my database.  I'm able to create the check boxes dynamically on form load, and also save the user's selections on close.  The problem is if a record is deleted in the database, then the users selections change because there's nothing about the checkedlistbox items that tie them to the primary key on the table.  I'm storing the user's selections as an arraylist collection type user setting.

How can I store both the **name and the primary key** so that when the database changes, it doesn't effect a user's selections?

Here's my code:

```
Public Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim conn As New ADODB.Connection()
        Dim database As String = "mydatabase"

        conn.CommandTimeout = 50400  '14 hours
        conn.Open("Provider=myprovider;Data Source=myserver;Initial Catalog=" & database & ";Integrated Security=SSPI")
        conn.CursorLocation = ADODB.CursorLocationEnum.adUseClient
        Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset()

        Dim Sql As String
        Sql = "SELECT ProcessID, ProcessName FROM mytable WHERE is_active = 1"

        rs.Open(Sql, conn)

        Dim cnt As Integer

        If rs.BOF = True And rs.EOF = True Then
            cnt = 0
        Else
            rs.MoveFirst()
            cnt = rs.RecordCount
        End If

        Dim i As Integer
        i = 0

        While i < cnt
            CheckedListBox1.Items.Add(rs.Fields(1).Value)
            i = i + 1
            rs.MoveNext()
        End While

        'get user settings
        Me.email.Checked = My.Settings.email
        Me.pop.Checked = My.Settings.pop

        Dim index As Integer
        For Each item As String In My.Settings.selectedlistbox

            index = CheckedListBox1.Items.IndexOf(item)

            If index = -1 Then
                CheckedListBox1.SetItemChecked(item, True)
            Else
                CheckedListBox1.SetItemChecked(item, False)
            End If
        Next

 End Sub
```

Comment: problem #1 may be your assumption that a ProcessID is a good candidate for a Primary key.  is that what you are doing?  If not, you really just need to save the ID of those checked in settings, as before use a Class of {ID, Text} to link them

Comment: the processid is the primary key from the table, which is not repeated.

Comment: Ok. but given the names, if it comes from System.Diagnostics, it is not immutable (processID 5412 today may not be the same tomorrow).  How does saving the Text of the things checked as a setting not work?

Comment: I'm confused.  ProcessID is my own generated auto imcrementing Primary key, it's not associated with a system process, if that's what you're saying.  Right now there are 5 records on the table with ProcessID's from 1 through 5.  My issue is that if I later say that processID # 2 is no longer active, then all my checked boxes in the application shift up one bc process 2 is no longer "there".  So it effectively changes my user selections.

Comment: Ok, I was just being sure.  the code you list for finding the setting in the CLB is incorrect.  `SetItemChecked` takes and integer and a Bool, you are passing a string.  The "=-1" is also copied incorrectly from the code I gave you.  You *should* be able to save the text of the items the user selected, then find them and check them.  When you save again, be sure to remove the old ones or they just accumulate

Comment: The code from the other question wasn't working right, when I changed it from <> to =, it started working as desired.  Not

Comment: -1 means the item was not found, so you have other problems, if checking items that are not found works.  It might be accumulation, if you dont clear out old selections, especially if things get added - it will *look* like they moved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a simple class and override the ToString function:

```
Private Class ProcessItem
  Public Property ProcessID As Integer = 0
  Public Property ProcessName As String = String.Empty

  Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
    Return Me.ProcessName
  End Function
End Class
```

Then you can add your information:

```
CheckedListBox1.Items.Add(New ProcessItem With { _
                              .ProcessID = rs.Fields(0).Value, _
                              .ProcessName = rs.Fields(1).Value})
```

Comment: This seems like it should work, but it doesn't effect anything.  Maybe I'm not implementing it right.  I'm pretty new to VB.